# Botium test cases fail intermittently and inconsistently

Tags: automated-tests, chatbot

It seems that my chatbot test cases run via Botium are failing intermittently and inconsistently.  The chatbot uses DialogFlow in part. A scheduler asks a user if they want to listen to music, etc.  If music is playing, the user may ask the chatbot to stop/cancel the music.

I already tried increasing the timeout.  In the botium.json file in my project directory, I have added the capability:      "WAITFORBOTTIMEOUT":50000,

Here are the first few files in my testset directory:
Cancel.convo.txt:

```
Cancel

#me
Cancel_input

#bot
Cancel_output_0
```

Cancel_input.utterances.txt:

```
Cancel_input
could you stop
enough music
music off
stop playing the music
can you stop the music
turn off music
enough
can you stop playing music please
stop the music
stop playing
stop
I give up
forget it
not now
stop it
cancel
never mind
go away
be quiet
shut up
i'm busy
```

Cancel_output_0.utterances.txt:

```
Cancel_output_0
Cancelled
```

Log output:

```
Botium Test-Suite
    1) Cancel/Cancel_input-L1
    ✓ Cancel/Cancel_input-L10 (441ms)
    2) Cancel/Cancel_input-L11
    ✓ Cancel/Cancel_input-L12 (245ms)
    3) Cancel/Cancel_input-L13
    4) Cancel/Cancel_input-L14
    ✓ Cancel/Cancel_input-L15 (283ms)
    5) Cancel/Cancel_input-L16
    ✓ Cancel/Cancel_input-L17 (286ms)
    ✓ Cancel/Cancel_input-L18 (269ms)
    ✓ Cancel/Cancel_input-L19 (264ms)
    ✓ Cancel/Cancel_input-L2 (264ms)
    ✓ Cancel/Cancel_input-L20 (256ms)
    ✓ Cancel/Cancel_input-L21 (303ms)
    ✓ Cancel/Cancel_input-L3 (301ms)
    6) Cancel/Cancel_input-L4
    ✓ Cancel/Cancel_input-L5 (230ms)
    ✓ Cancel/Cancel_input-L6 (262ms)
    ✓ Cancel/Cancel_input-L7 (284ms)
...
```

Comment: more info please - what kind of chatbot ? log output ?

Comment: I already posted the log output above, but neglected to label it.  Now I have added a label to it.  (I assume the check marks mean the test passed, and the numerals count the errors?)  I also added a brief description above about the kind of chatbot, but I'm not sure if this answers your question?

Comment: Currently, I'm just using the test set generated automatically by Botium from the Dialogflow agent zip file exported from Dialogflow.  All these tests perform correctly in the Dialogflow simulator.

Comment: Would it be possible to share your agent.zip with me (by email) ?

Comment: I emailed it to you yesterday.  Did you receive it?